# How to write a query to get data count with combination of codision

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join

I have two tables named [DrugPrescriptionEdition] and  [PrescriptionDoseDetail]  and now, I join that two tables using the below query and taking a result set.

```
select * from   DrugPrescription dp where id in(
  SELECT   distinct  dpe.template
  FROM [DrugPrescriptionEdition] dpe
  join PrescriptionDoseDetail pdd on pdd.prescription = dpe.id 
   where doseEnd_endDate is NULL and doseEnd_doseEndType =1
   )
```

but now I want to take records only contain, (1,2) combination of 'datasource' column and prescription.id should be same.

Example : like records { prescriptionID =4 and there contain ,(1,2) }. I will not consider, only 1 ,or 2 contain records.

[image]

Need some expert help to adding this conditions  to my above query and modify it .

Expected result :  I need to filter out , above query result using this, new condition too.

[image]

Comment: Could you Include some sample data and expected outcome using that data?

Comment: @DT add draft how i expected results.

Comment: I'm confused by your question.  You show a query with multiple tables.  Then you show a single table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ,i used multiple table ,  i put draft 3 images ,to explain what am i expected...!!! it is very hard to me , explain, without draft visualizing.

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume your records are in a single table.  Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from t
where (t.dataSource = 1 and
       exists (select 1 
               from t t2
               where t2. prescriptionid = t.prescriptionid and
                     t2.dataSource = 2
              )
      ) or
      (t.dataSource = 2 and
       exists (select 1 
               from t t2
               where t2.prescriptionid = t.prescriptionid and
                     t2.dataSource = 2
              )
      );
```

It is unclear if any other data sources are allowed.  If they are not, then add:

```
and
not exists (select 1
            from t t3
            where t3.prescriptionid = t.prescriptionid and
                  t3.dataSource not in (1, 2)
           )
```